# Input stream - closing

Tags: input, prolog, inputstream

How to close an input stream in SWI-Prolog using `<CTRL>+<D>` combination ?

```
bot:-
   repeat,
     write('>'),
     readln(X), nl,
     answer(X, Answer),
     write(Answer), nl,
    end(X).

end(X):-member('end',X).

Where X is a list of keywords to that bot
```

How should I modify source code to get that result?

Comment: now if I type :'end' i get some default sentence and 'true'value what makes that stream closed, but how to change it to CTRL+D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already found a solution.
To get that result I have to apply **at_end_of_stream** and cut "**!**".

```
bot:-
    write('Hello'),
    nl,
    write('>'),
    repeat,
    readln(X),
    answer(X, Answer),
    write(Answer),
    nl,
    write('>'),
    at_end_of_stream, !.
```

Last two lines of code makes it works as I expect.
Now when using combination `Ctrl+D` we can stop it (close stream which is the same what turning bot off).

@larsmans: Nice to know that `readln` is bad or just not optimal. Maybe next time I will use that tip. :)

Answer (score 2):

As SWI-Prolog dev lead Jan Wielemaker [recommends](http://www.rhinocerus.net/forum/lang-prolog/203438-swi-prolog-undocumented-predicates.html#post1112820):

> [`readln` is] something from old practice. It isn't very well defined. Use the `library(readutil)` predicates. Those are documented and way better designed.

Comment: Hmm but that lib. doesn't solve my problem .. or maybe it did and i haven't seen that